# java.sql.Statement.EXECUTE_FAILED Scenario in Spring JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am making use of org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(String, Collection, int, ParameterizedPreparedStatementSetter) method in Spring jdbcTemplate class to perform Batch update.

To note the result of batch operation, this method returns an array of array containing following 3 status codes for each SQL in the batch.

```
java.sql.Statement.EXECUTE_FAILED
java.sql.Statement.SUCCESS_NO_INFO
An Integer value greater than 0 stating no. of records affected.
```

I tried to know the scenario when EXECUTE_FAILED gets returned. So, I purposely tried to insert a record which is already exist in table so that operation should fail on DB with primary key violation error. It failed but I received the failure in the form of Exception :

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.
```

I was expecting the error code to be returned in this case.

Do anyone here knows, what is the exact scenario when the error code of     `java.sql.Statement.EXECUTE_FAILED` is returned by jdbctemplate ?

Answer (score 0):

This completely depends on the relevant JDBC connector implementation you will be using. 
Checkout the [MariaDB(The far better "CLONE" of mysql) Java Connector](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-connector-j) 
 implementation on how they give meaning to these values

- [MariaDbStatement - LINE 1019](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-connector-j/blob/26918b7d1e92167edd652a7f562160a945cec981/src/main/java/org/mariadb/jdbc/MariaDbStatement.java#L1019)
- [MariaDbPreparedStatementClient -
  LINE 180](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-connector-j/blob/26918b7d1e92167edd652a7f562160a945cec981/src/main/java/org/mariadb/jdbc/MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java#L180)